# Parallel processing in odi

Tags: multithreading, oracle-data-integrator

I want to run a scenario in odi parallely with a condition.
For ex if the year in table is 2015 or 2016 or so on it should run parallely and store in the target table without creating multiple scenarios .
How do I do that using asynchronous type in odi and without having to create multiple mappings.

Comment: use a variable for the year, generate the scenario and execute it in parallel in a package/load plan?

Comment: I have a single mapping where in I want to run the process parallely on the basis of year and store it in target table, how can I do this with scenario and where to put the variable in package

Comment: Add a filter on the date or year column in your mapping. The condition should use the variable. Something like `SRC.EVENTYEAR = #PROJECT.V_YEAR` or `SRC.EVENTDATE >= TO_DATE(#PROJECT.V_YEAR||'0101', 'YYYYMMDD') AND SRC.EVENTDATE < TO_DATE(#PROJECT.V_YEAR+1||'0101', 'YYYYMMDD')`. Then generate a scenario and pass a value to the variable starting the scenario.

Comment: I want to filter out on multiple years for ex 2007,2008,2009 and so on parallely without having to create multiple mappings..Thank you

Comment: You need only one mapping if you use a variable. Just pass a different value for the year every time you call it.

Comment: Thank you Jerome, can you please help me with the new problem I got, I have posted a new question on my profile.